# Connecting Django web interfaces with Python

Tags: python, django

I am trying to connect a button on my web interface to a program running behind Python. I feel it sounds weird so I'm just going to give a scenario for better visualisation of the problem.

When a submit button is clicked on the web application, it will call a function running behind a python program on the back end to process the submitted information (encryption/converting the data into another format) then store it in a database or file server.

How do I code it on Django as well as in Python?

Comment: This question is a rather broad one, and you provide very little information. What have you tried already? Please try solving your problem and only ask here when you have a specific problem or question. If you don't know how to start building a web app with Python and Django, I can recommend e.g. [this tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/), which covers the basics and does not require any programming knowledge to start with. There's plenty of other learning materials too, it only takes a web search to find dozens of them. Good luck!

Comment: @natka_m I have tried searching for answers regarding this but I have not found any relevant results to my problem. Maybe its the keyword that I have been using during my search. I do not know what is the term used by web developers for "linking" web app with a programming language on the backend. However I do know that for a programming language to interact with a database (like MySQL), a "mysql.connector" has to be imported and called using "mysql.connector.connect()"

Comment: Welcome to SO! As pointed by @natka_m, you need to rephrase your question to attract attention and answers. In its current forn the question lacks "specificity" and does not show your previous effort. It will immensely help others if you can add a small code snipped that reproduces/demonstrates the problem you are facing. Kindly consider reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to frame questions that are easy to understand and get answered quickly.

Comment: @vvy isn't "Connecting Django web interface with Python" specific enough? I seriously do not know how specific do I need to get as I don't even have a clue on how to solve my current problem. For web developers it would be an easy thing but for me it is not as I have just started web development for the first time and I need my front end to connect to my back-end (Python). All my search results are leading me to developing web apps with Flask/Django. I am not a really good programmer so i am unable to describe my problems in "programming language".

Comment: You have mentioned that you have a web interface, you are able to create a button (probably a form to enter user information too) and now you want to code it in Django. This will require you to go through at least one Django tutorial. If you are willing to learn Django, this is covered in [Writing your first Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/) and also  in [this tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_start_project/) referred by @natka_m.  So don't be overwhelmed by initial tedious setup of Django, it is worth.